# Flutter errors Exceptions customTrace and fromJSON

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, stack-trace, fromjson

When clicking on the link in E/flutter (17214)#0 I get the (E) highlighted.

catch (e) {
print(CustomTrace(StackTrace.current, message: e));

[image]

on the second image in E/flutter E/flutter (17214)#1, I get this highlighted (fromJSON)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here is that you are not really deserializing all the data you are getting properly, the dart analyzer is telling you that "noSuchMethodError" is not a Type of String.

This essentially means that you are supposed to have a String somewhere but you are using "noSuchMethodError". The dart analyzer wants you to check your *fromJson* Method and change somethings.

It would help better if you could show your *fromJson* method.

Comment: Thank you very much, it gave me an insight on where the mistakes were.

One hurdle passed, there are other mistakes I need to tend to.